# How can you use Spring-roo, hibernate-spatial, Postgres 9.3 , postgis 2 for reverse engineering for spatial types like geometry(Polygon,4258)?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgis, spring-roo, spatial

First I added hibernate-spatial to org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa to 1.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from yesterday.

By doing the following changes in the code for  org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa

new lines to addon-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/roo/addon/jpa/JdbcDatabase.java

```
HIBERNATE_SPATIAL_POSTGIS("HIBERNATE_SPATIAL_POSTGIS", "org.postgresql.Driver",
        "jdbc:postgresql://HOST_NAME:5432"), //
```

new lines to addon-jpa/src/main/resources/org/springframework/roo/addon/jpa/jpa-dialects.properties

```
HIBERNATE.HIBERNATE_SPATIAL_POSTGIS=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

new lines to addon-jpa/src/main/resources/org/springframework/roo/addon/jpa/configuration.xml

```
        <database id="HIBERNATE_SPATIAL_POSTGIS">
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
                <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
                <version>1.13</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </database>
```

In the postgres database I have a column  geo which is  geometry(Polygon,4258)

Then I run the following spring-roo command 
“jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HIBERNATE_SPATIAL_POSTGIS” and that works ok.

When I run “database introspect --schema sde_ar5”

I get the following type for geo column in the response :

```
column name="geo" primaryKey="false" required="false" scale="0" size="2147483647" type="1111,geometry"
```

The I run the command 
“database reverse engineer --schema sde_ar5 --package no.skogoglandskap.reveng.sde_ar5”

The result type is the string for column geo and not com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon

```
@Column(name = "geo")
private String Ar5Flate.geo;
```

Anybody know how get reverse engineering to work correctly with hibernate-spatial and spring-roo ?

Thanks Lars

Answer (score 1):

DBRE addon uses JDBC driver metadata to instrospect the DB. As the driver only knows JVM types, it doesn't know custom Hibernate types like JTS Polygon, this is the reason because you get the type String.

You should customize the geo field as needed.

Comment: Ok, they I drop to use spring-roo for this reverse engineering and start to test hibernate-tools(4.3.1.CR1) instead.